# Not selecting duplicate records with unique keys

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample table:

Table Movies:

```
Title   | Year | Price | Genre | ID
Batman    2016    12     Comic  1
Avengers  2014    7      Comic  2
Batman    2016    7      Comic  3
Fast 5    2012    7      Car    4
Superman                        5
Star Wars                       6
```

Desired Result:

```
Title   | Year | ID
Batman    2016   1
Avengers  2014   2
Fast 5    2012   4
Superman         5
Star Wars        6
```

So I need to select distinct ID, Title and Year where Title and Year aren't duplicates. Note Title and Year will always be the same if it is a duplicate so for example Batman 2014 wouldn't be a choice. If it was a duplicate both title and year would be the same as the duplicate record. Basically need to not select duplicate records that have unique keys. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Edit: one other thing. Be aware that null values might be present and I don't want those omitted. I updated the example to show this.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: How do you decide which `ID` to show in case of duplicates? For `Batman` you have two rows and you want the `ID = 1`, why?

Comment: Good question. It doesn't matter. We want an id but it can be any of them it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a row_number, partition by the distinct fields and order by another

```
with CTE as
(
select a1.*, row_number() over (partition by Title, Year order by ID) as r_ord
from Movies a1
)
select CTE.*
from CTE
where r_ord =1
```

or, if you only want the Title, Year and ID:

```
select Title, Year, min(ID)
from movies
group by Title, Year
```